# How to validate data when validateRequest is set to "false"

Tags: asp.net, validate-request

Do sites like Stackoverflow or asp.net use validateRequest= "false" at their page directive? If "Yes" then how they are checking the user input and if "NO" then how they are able to postback the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main things [Validate Request](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/) is looking for are < and > characters, to stop you opening your site up to malicious users posting script and or HTML to your site.

Answer to the second question When **ValidateRequst="false"**

**When request validation is disabled, content can be submitted to a page; it is the responsibility of the page developer to ensure that content is properly encoded or processed**

**For the encoding data :** Content can be easily HTML-encoded on the server using the `Server.HtmlEncode(string)` API. Content can also be easily HTML-decoded, that is, reverted back to standard HTML using the `Server.HtmlDecode(string`) method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not the complete answer, I just want to know that how these sites are dealing with the malicious inputs, just in case if they make ValidateRequest = false? I mean how they are verifying the input at the server side if they disablle validate request.

Comment: read the article link -- by the way by encoding data they avoid script attach -- go to article which give you more info : http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/

Comment: So does it mean that doing Encoding at server side called as the validation of malicious input at server side ??

Comment: yes that only thing you can do if validaterequest is set to false